# jsp jump url parameters' names are the html elements' names

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I write web front page page.jsp:

```
<select id="type_label" name="type_label">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach items="${types}" var="type" varStatus="status">
        <option value="${type}">${type}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>


function dosearch(){
    var type_label = document.getElementById("type_label");
    var tagVal = type_label.options[type_label.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location="${ctx}/content/query?tag="+tagVal;
}
```

In controller Controller.java:
I get the data rows of mysql and put these data rows in List list.
Then put the list in model:
model.add("list", list);
The list has data rows in my log.

Then the controller make the page jump to page.jsp.
The project use rose java web frame.

return "content/page";
It make the page jump to page.jsp.

But the url is:
http://127.0.0.1:3428/web/content/page?type_label=%E6%90%9E%E7%AC%91&currentPage=
The url is expected to be:
http://127.0.0.1:3428/web/content/page?tag=%E6%90%9E%E7%AC%91&currentPage=

The url's parameter is type_label and not tag.
But type_label is select html element's id.

Why？Please give me a hand.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason about it.
After dosearch() executed, got the list of the tag from mysql.
Then jumped to content/page.jsp by

```
return "content/page";
```

The page would load by the form:

```
<form action="${ctx}/content/page" method="get" name="Form" id="Form"
class="form-horizontal">
```

It would get data list from mysql again. **Because it got tag parameter by the tag element's name "type_label".
Then its url was "..type_label=tagname".** The controller's method didn't get tag parameter from "type_label". So it had no tag parameter now.
It would get data list without tag.
So the data list was not the data of this tag.

Solution:
The tag element in HTML is that:

```
<select id="tag" name="tag">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach items="${tag}" var="tag" varStatus="status">
        <option value="${tag}">${tag}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Modify the dosearch() method to this:

```
function dosearch(){
    $("#form").submit();
}
```

And modify the controller code to get tag parameter. Like that:

```
@Get("page")
public String page(Model model, @Param("tag") String tag){
...
}
```

The controller will get tag parameter by the tag element's name "tag".
After dosearch() executed, the controller will get tag parameter from the form.
Then get the data list of this tag in controller. And add list to model.
At last the page will show the list of the tag.